# Авторизация через url

Tags: url, авторизация

Всем привет) Такой вопрос можно ли авторизоваться на сайте введя Логин и Пароль после адреса самого сайта. Что-то типо такого: www.vk.com/login=aaa&pass=1111. И если это возможно подскажите, что надо вводить.

Comment: под сайтом вы имеете ввиду вк?

Comment: Зависит от сайта. Если он такое позволяет, то да, можно:)

Comment: А как можно узнать позволяет ли сайт такой доступ?

Comment: @dinnua, спросить у администратора или разработчика сайта.

Answer (score 2):

Подобный способ авторизации не оправдан, так как любой, кто увидит вашу историю браузера сможет залогинится.

Comment: И не только. Сюда относятся, например, еще и поисковые роботы, которые получают данные от вашего браузера и исследуют посещенные страницы.

Comment: Хорошо, а как тогда по другому можна авторизироваться? Я помню где то читал, что в браузера есть файл где храняться логини и пароли. Можно ли как то через него?